# SUMIFS and SUMIF for Google Sheet doesnt work for DATE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

Google Sheets is NOT able to distinguish between Dates in  SUMIF, has anyone a alternative solution?

Anyways the bad thing is, that this formula cant disting date criterias.

### Example1:

```
=SUMIFS(G2:G100;D2:D100;">=01.06.2011";F2:F100;"<=30.07.2011")
```

Does work, but this example 2 doesnt work:

### Example 2:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(D2:D100 & F2:F100;">=01.06.2011"&"<=30.07.2011";G2:G100)))
```

I Dont know why it doesnt work, has anybody a solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Google [Sheets SUMIF formulas for dates](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/03/15/sumif-google-sheets/#sumif-dates) blog post guide:

> To conditionally sum values based on date criteria, you also use the
>   comparison operators like shown in the above examples. The key point
>   is that a date should be supplied in the format that Google Sheets can
>   understand.
>
> For instance, to sum amounts in B5:B13 for delivery dates prior to
>   11-Mar-2018, build the criterion in one of these ways:
>
> ```
> =SUMIF(C5:C13, "<3/11/2018", B5:B13)
>
> =SUMIF(C5:C13, "<"&DATE(2018,3,11), B5:B13)
>
> =SUMIF(C5:C13, "<"&B1, B5:B13)
> ```